# How does a parent cope with an opposing disposition to his/her own?

Tags: behavior, social-development, relationships

So I have never been one of those women that gets super dramatic or excited about seeing people (except for when my brother came home from the Gulf War).  If I see the person regularly, I'm glad to see them but feel no urge to go running and screaming into a hug with excitement.

My child **is** one of those girls.

Now, it isn't **just** the running and hugging thing - its just that this is the best, clearest, easiest example to offer in regard to beginning to pose my question.

She also loves going to the bathroom in a crowd and has to gather a few friends to go with her when in a public place (in addition to myself or another trusted adult), basically she is a "girls, girl" in this regard.  She's totally into wanting to wear makeup (I still only wear it when I must for a job, an interview . . . )

Sometimes, it makes me completely batty mostly because I don't understand the value in it.  As the adult, of course I'm able to see that she experiences value in it (as do many girls), but the squealing is over the top and unnecessary, the crowd to the bathroom is typical, but makes the whole process take twice as long. . .

I'm fine and all, but I know it is a common problem between parents and their kids just like "mood matching" can be a problem for a married or otherwise committed-and-living-together couple.  So how does one make sure the mis-matched dispositions don't create strife where there needn't be any.

Answer (score 3):

It has been pointed out to me that I am possibly the most laid back parent ever, so this guidance may not work for you, but my take on it is:

Everyone is different. If your daughter is happy being a 'girly girl' then I can't imagine there is anything wrong with that. Let her enjoy that aspect of her personality. It's not like it will impact you or others. She may well change as she gets older, or she may not (I have colleagues in both camps so who knows)

The important thing is that she is happy and well balanced - giggling/squealing etc are pretty irrelevant in the bigger picture.